# How to store data - should I duplicate it directly

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, storage

I want to store data of a variety of establishments.
I want to store data which allows the location of said establishment within its country.

As such I need to store Town data, County data, and Country data for each establishment.

I have a town, county, and country database respectively which are all linked together such that for example I can search for a town, its 'county_id' column matches the ID of a county in the county table etc.

I was wondering the best way to refer to this data from the actual establishment table.

At the moment in this table I simply have a town, county, and country column which contains the respective data.

My URL structure is website.com/country/county/town/name so having the data like this allows me to find an establishment with one query, and no joins etc.

What are the benefits of having just one column with a town ID and then querying with joins each time to find the county/country data? Obviously one benefit is if any data is changed it automatically updates per se. Another i suppose is it requires less database storage space.

On the other hand however it would require more queries.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're pretty much spot on with the remark: de-normalization generally helps with reads performance and does bad for write performance while normalization generally does the opposite.

Usually you do more reads than you do writes on a certain data. If that's the case for you, than I'd leave the data as is (with the duplicate town, county, etc in each establishment entry). It will be slower to update (more code, more validation, more time sending and executing the update) but lots faster to read (simpler query code, less time spend at the database side to execute the query, etc). I've recently worked on a project where the data was updated once a month, but read (displayed in a web app) many times a day, so we finally went from having a normalized database and lots of joins (either pseudo or actual), to a duplication of data similar to what you have here, and the read performance and responsiveness of the web app has increased significantly.

Oh and as far as database space (as in physical space occupied on the disk(s)), while it's theoretically true that normalizing your tables will reduce the space (sometimes significantly) this won't really impact reads and/or writes speeds significantly, so you're better off if you don't take this argument into account when only striving for performance (and are not concerned about disk space).

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no database space saving but the you could maintain changes very easy. Buy since towns don't change counties or countries, your db is safe like that!

Splitting it in this case would mean a cost of storage AND performance. If no additional data required, don't split it!